# Can I use a text file to set svn:externals in SharpSvn's SetProperty() method?

Tags: c#, sharpsvn

My aim is to set more than one externals (links) to a project so that anybody checking out the project should get all the externals at the same time. This can be achieved in SVN.EXE as  -  propset svn:externals -F svnexternalsfile .

How can I specify the external file in SetProperty() method in SharpSvn ?

Answer (score 3):

SharpSvn doesn't handle the file reading for you; it just allows setting properties.

```
using(SvnClient client = new SvnClient())
{
   string val = File.ReadAllText("C:\\My\\file.txt");

   client.SetProperty("C:\\WorkDir", SvnPropertyNames.SvnExternals, val);
}
```